# Delete keys from a hash by matching chars

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash with a few hundred values, some of which are:

```
plays = {"week 1" => 0, "week 2" => 0, etc}
```

I'd like to delete any key/value pairs whose key has the word `"week"` in it. It doesn't seem that I can do that with `plays.delete`. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let:

```
plays = { "week 1" => 0, "week 2" => 0, "dog" => "woof" }
```

If you don't want to damage `plays`, use [Hash#reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject):

```
plays.reject { |k,v| k.include?('week') }
  #=> "woof"

plays
  #=> {"week 1"=>0, "week 2"=>0, "dog"=>"woof"}
```

(I originally had `k =~ /week/`. I agree with @sawa that in this case it's best to avoid the regex.)

Comment: I think `String#include?` might be better than using a regex. I haven't tested, but I believe it should be faster.

Answer (score 4):

You can do use [`Hash#delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if).

```
play.delete_if { |k,_| /week/ ===  k }
```

I used this method : [`Regexp#===`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)

Comment: I think `String#include?` might be better than using a regex. I haven't tested, but I believe it should be faster.

Comment: Hum.. You are true I think.